# Calling Perl code from a WPF application

Tags: xml, wpf, perl, visual-studio-2010, data-munging

I want some sample code to learn how to call a perl module which processes input from a xml file in a Winform/WPF application and returns a transformed XML(basically I use Perl's data munging features) file in the directory or returns an error if the input XML is itself wrong. 
I'm developing on Windows 7 64bit, VS 2010.

Comment: Are you having problems with launching the external Perl executable (with script as parameter) from your main application, or with what should be in the script? Either way, what code do you have so far and how does it not work?

Comment: the perl script has the input xml filename as the parameter and outputs another xml. my wpf code would call the perl script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about WPF but there's an example of [calling an external program](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=373) I expect this approach would work with a Perl script.

You could create a simple Perl example program, for example based on the [XML::Simple documentation](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSimple) which could be tested in isolation before being invoked from your WPF program.

You might find it useful to ask individual questions about specific issues. For example can you exchange data with an external programs without using files as intermediary containers? Can you use STDIN and STDOUT to pass data to and from external filter-style programs that read data from STDIN and write transformed data, or results, to STDOUT.

If you are using C# (rather than say VB) you should probably say so explicitly.